# Git pull cannot allocate memory

Tags: git

I tried searching various other post but could not resolve my issue.
Below is the error message that I get while doing `git pull`

> error: cannot fork() for rev-list: Cannot allocate memory
>
> error: Could not run `git rev-list`
>
> error: cannot fork() for fetch-pack: Cannot allocate memory

I tried below command but unable to resolve it,

1. git config --add core.bigFileThreshold 4m
2. git gc --aggressive --prune=now
   This command failed to run unpack

Only the thing is that, there are many branches(100+). And the repo size is just 9MB (each file not greater than 100kb).

I thought of cloning the repo at some other location, but the clone failed with same error.

Comment: what is your OS ? what is your git version ?

Comment: Ubuntu:14.04 and git version: 1.9.1

Comment: Do you still have this bug after a reboot ?

Comment: Is the problem with git the only bug you have in your system ? or do you see bugs pop from other programs too ?

Comment: Oh gr8. Other programs also had same issue. RAM usage was almost near to 90%-95%+. There was one process which was trying to utilize RAM memory, stopping this worked. Thanks for you help.

Comment: The cause for OP's problem was not linked to any specific git problem

Answer (score 16):

This happens when your **machine does not have enough memory**.
It can be because of one or more **processes that are consuming too much memory**. To solve this, you have to **quit the memory consuming process**.

**Rebooting your OS** may also help fix this issue. If rebooting didn't help, there is some memory expensive process that starts at system startup.

In **Linux** systems, please try the following:

1. In terminal execute the command `ps aux --sort -rss` to list processes sorted by RAM usage.
2. Note down the `PID` (process id) of first one or two processes in the list. (You can identify the process from column name `COMMAND`)
3. Save any unsaved changes in that process by switching to its window.
4. Use the `kill` command to kill that process. eg: `kill 11234` (where 11234 is the PID)
5. Now try `git pull` or whatever git command you were trying

In **Windows**, use **Task manager** to find and stop the memory consuming process or task.

In **Mac OS** you can use the built-in **Activity Monitor** app to find the culprit (Use the memory tab)

Comment: The only big memory consumer is X11, but when I kill that from a textual TTY, even then the system hangs.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus I don't know much about X11. AFAIK, X11 is a windowing system and kill it all of a sudden will make your system hang. Please check if there is any graceful way to shut it down. Then try `git pull` again.

Comment: Whenever it's shut down it auto-restarts and I couldn't find why or how. I went with removing xfce4 and reinstalling it later.

Comment: I tried first to just restart the server (Gunicorn and Nginx) because I was using Django. It helped me. Your answers gave me that idea. Thanks.

Comment: I had to use `kill -9 <pid>`

Answer (score 0):

I face this issue because my server ram got full.
You can check your server ram by using command line.
`ps aux --sort -rss`
It will show in percentages.[image]

Note: Am used ubuntu O/S.